# Is it not possible to create a .NET Visual Basic console application?

Tags: vb.net, console-application, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio 2022 does not seem to offer the option to use .NET 6?

[image]

[image]

Not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

".NET Framework" is specifically the Windows version of .NET, which stopped at 4.x. You want the other option in your screenshot, which is for the new .NET, just known as ".NET" (without "Framework").